# without div: text an headline with background over an image

Tags: css

i want to place the headline + text with background color over the image (in the upper right corner) but I don´t know if it could work without a div around the h1 and p tag. 
could it work with chained selectors? im a little bit baffled. how would you solve this positioning question?

Here´s my code:

```
<div class="class1 class2 ">
        <h1>headline</h1>
        <p>text</p>
        <figure class="class3 class4">
              <img class="at2x" width="950" height="609" alt="" src="">
        </figure>
</div>
```

and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HpDnS/1/)

Comment: Can you set the image as a background of div element? This could be most proper and semantic solution, I guess.

Comment: thank you for your answer! its not possible right now because I do only the css job for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you wrote you can't use image as background, imho you should do it like in [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tLAxB).

**HTML**

```
<div class="class1 class2 ">
        <h1>headline</h1>
        <p>text</p>
        <figure class="class3 class4">
          <img class="at2x" width="950" height="609" alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/950/609">
        </figure>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.class1 {
  position: relative;
}
.class3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

This is of course one of the options.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, obviously a `class` rather than `style=` would be better:

```
<div class="class1 class2" style="position: relative">
    <h1 style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; background-color: #DDD;">headline</h1>
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 20px; background-color: #DDD;">text</p>
    <figure class="class3 class4" style="position: absolute; top:0; left: 0;">
        <img class="at2x" width="950" height="609" alt="" src="">
    </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `<figcaption>` tag, in relation to the `<figure>` tag :

```
<div class="class1 class2 ">
    <figure class="class3 class4">
          <img class="at2x" width="950" height="609" alt="" src="">
          <figcaption>
              <h1>headline</h1>
              <p>text</p>
          </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

I suggest to put you `<figure>` in `relative` position and `<figcaption>` in `absolute`.

Be careful, Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the `<figure>` tag.

Read more about this stuff [here](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/).